# python math.acos inverse cosine issues

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I need to find an angle of a triangle with only three coordinate points on a plane. In regular trigonometry at the end of the equation i would use:

```
cos = (a ** 2) - (b ** 2) - (c ** 2) / -2 * b * c
```

I used the `**` operator for to the power of, and `sideA`, `sideB` and `sideC` are the lengths of the sides of the triangle.

I am currently using `math.acos()` to find the angle, but I'm getting a math domain error. Is `math.acos()` the right function to use for what I understand as the inverse cosine?

Here is a excerpt of code from my program:

```
x = 100
y = 100
centerX = x + 50
centerY = y + 50

if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            mousex, mousey = event.pos
            sideA = math.sqrt((x - mousex)**2)+((y - mousey)**2)
            sideB = math.sqrt((centerX - mousex)**2)+((centerY - mousey)**2)
            sideC = math.sqrt((centerX - x)**2)+((centerY - y)**2)
            cos = float(sideA**2)-(sideB**2)-(sideC**2)/(-2*(sideB*sideC))
            angle = math.acos(cos)
            print angle
```

What am i doing wrong? When I enter the numbers from my program into my calculator I get the right angle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem here is that your code is formatted so badly, you can't see the errors with parentheses that you're making.

### Error 1

For instance, this line:

```
sideA = math.sqrt((x - mousex)**2)+((y - mousey)**2)
```

when formatted properly, looks like this:

```
sideA = math.sqrt((x - mousex) ** 2) + ((y - mousey) ** 2)
```

and when you remove the redundant parentheses, you can see what's happening even more clearly:

```
sideA = math.sqrt((x - mousex) ** 2) + (y - mousey) ** 2
```

You're only passing the square of *one* of your sides to `math.sqrt()`, and just adding the square of the second side to it. It should be:

```
sideA = math.sqrt((x - mousex) ** 2 + (y - mousey) ** 2)
```

or even better:

```
sideA = math.hypot(x - mousex, y - mousey)
```

### Error 2

Then this line:

```
cos = float(sideA**2)-(sideB**2)-(sideC**2)/(-2*(sideB*sideC))
```

has a similar problem - you're missing parentheses around those first three terms, and you're only dividing the square of side C by 2bc. It should be:

```
cos = (sideA ** 2 - sideB ** 2 - sideC ** 2) / ( -2 * sideB * sideC)
```

### Solution

As a result of the above, you're not calculating the cosine correctly, so what you're passing to `math.acos()` is way out of an allowable range for a cosine (a cosine will always be in the range `-1 <= cos A <= 1`), so it's giving you that domain error. Printing out your values would have helped see you were getting something really strange, here.

Here's a fixed and working version of your program, modified to just set values directly for `mousex` and `mousey`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math

x, y = 100, 100
centerX, centerY = x + 50, y + 50
mousex, mousey = 100,150 

sideA = math.hypot(x - mousex, y - mousey);
sideB = math.hypot(centerX - mousex, centerY - mousey)
sideC = math.hypot(centerX - x, centerY - y)
cosA = (sideB ** 2 + sideC ** 2 - sideA ** 2) / (2 * sideB * sideC)
angle = math.acos(cosA)

print "sideA: %.2f, sideB: %.2f, sideC: %.2f" % (sideA, sideB, sideC)
print "cosA: %.6f" % (cosA)
print "angle: %.2f radians, %.2f degrees" % (angle, math.degrees(angle))
```

which outputs:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./angle.py
sideA: 50.00, sideB: 50.00, sideC: 70.71
cosA: 0.707107
angle: 0.79 radians, 45.00 degrees
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

I've taken the liberty of rearranging your cosine rule calculation slightly to eliminate the need to negate the denominator.

Comment: never noticed i didnt accept a answer. You deserve that rep!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `math.acos` is the correct function for inverse cosine.

Your error is elsewhere, but without exact samples of your input, we can't help you much. What line produces an error? What's the error message?

Comment: The error comes on the  math.acos (cos) line thank you for your help also for my test trials x, y and centerX centerY are constants mouseX mouseY are the mouses x y cords on the screen a trail I ran was using the cords 58 and 102 for mouseX and mouseY and I got 17.39 (rounded) as my answer but if I run those numbers in my program I get a error on the acos any ideas?

Comment: No, I don't because your description is, again, vague. Please give us a minimal reproduction case -- a few lines of code that we can actually run on our computers with no prerequisites other than Python, and produces the error you encountered.